# JavaScript: Setting Up Preloader

Tags: javascript

I've made a simple preloader but I want it to disappear after the page loaded plus two seconds.

How do I do it?

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("Preloader");
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    loader.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
#Preloader {
    background: #000 url(https://gph.is/g/46ql32M) no-repeat center center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div id="Preloader"></dv>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method to delay the update of the `display` property:

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("Preloader");
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000)
})
```

```css
#Preloader {
  background: #000 url(https://gph.is/g/46ql32M) no-repeat center center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div id="Preloader"></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

PS: `https://gph.is/g/46ql32M` is not a direct link to the preloader image